# No package matching 'maven' found available, installed or updated.

Tags: ansible

When i use yum module in an ansible playbook to install maven on the target server, i get this error message: No package matching 'maven' found available, installed or updated

But when i log on to the target server, i could successfully install maven with yum install maven

Not sure what is wrong with the playbook. Where should i look for any further logs or how to resolve this issue?

playbook task looks like:

```
- name: install maven (and other packages if needed)
  yum: name=maven state=latest
  become: true
```

Comment: try rpm -qa on target server (after you've installed it manually) to see how this packet is really named. May be it's a difference on handling of metapackages.

Comment: this is what i get when i run rpm -qa maven-wagon-2.4-3.el7.noarch
maven-3.0.5-17.el7.noarch. Even after using these names, the error remains same, only the message will have the new name in it.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I found that yum module doesn't update cache by default, but rpm (on command line) does.

Try to add `update_cache: yes` to yum module parameters.

Comment: - name: install maven (and other packages if needed)  
  yum: name=maven state=latest update_cache=yes  
  become: true

Comment: Ok, then try to use `-vvvvv` option of ansible, may be it would clarify. Or, check /var/log/syslog on a target system.

... Wait a minute. Try to use `state=installed`, may be you have a dependency issue and the latest version does not fit.

Comment: state=installed returns same error. with -vvvvv option, i get this in the error message. "{"module_args": {"allow_downgrade": false, "name": ["maven"], "bugfix": false, "list": null, "disable_gpg_check": false, "conf_file": null, "install_repoquery": true, "validate_certs": true, "state": "installed", "disablerepo": null, "update_cache": true, "disable_plugin": [], "enablerepo": null, "exclude": null, "security": false, "update_only": false, "enable_plugin": [], "installroot": "/", "skip_broken": false}}, "msg": "No package matching \'maven\' found available, installed or updated"}"

Comment: try validate_certs=false, and see syslog output on the target hot.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, please anyone let me know if any work around is found ?